# For what does the - stands in "tar -czf - directory"

Tags: unix, tar

I am using this command blindly from a forum when I like to backup files from my servers to a local one with

```
ssh user@domain.com "tar -czf - directory" > destination.tar.gz
```

But I am starting to wonder what the minus between czf and directory means. With the plain command *tar -czf - directory* I am getting *gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal.*

Is the minus in this context a special char for the bash to tell the system to output the content to be used in a pipe or is that a special option for tar alone? I did not find anything about it in the tar manual.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells `tar` (on the remote machine) to send its output (which is the tar archive) to `stdout`, which the shell (on the local machine) then redirects to a file called `destination.tar.gz` also on the local machine.

Comment: Is this option tar or bash specific? Can I use the minus sign always instead of a filename to redirect its output to stdout?

Comment: Not **always**, but it is quite commonly accepted. An alternative to try if not is `/dev/stdout`

Comment: Some programs, `tr` for example, are pure filters and don't take an output file (or input file) at all.